# SlidingMenu - Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-resources, sliding

**Error:**

I got and error of Resources$NotFoundException in this line `setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_and_titles);` I already tested many others layout, I just got a working sample and tried to change the layout to the working one, but Always got this error, whatever I do.

I am using SlidingMenu, ViewPagerIndicator and SherlockActionBar.

**SlidingFragmentActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    protected ListFragment mFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_and_titles);

        // set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        mFrag = new SampleListFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
        t.commit();

        // customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.actionbar_home_width);
        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);

        mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    }

01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.example.nightid.main.BaseSampleActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040060 type #0x12 is not valid
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 13:10:28.224: E/AndroidRuntime(899):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
```

Comment: save all, clean project. That should do it.

Comment: I really hope was that, but isn't, I tried and still got this error, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the search function in eclipse, search for

> #### "0x7f040060"

---

or go to

> #### projectfolder/gen/path/R.java that contains your resources.

You'll find something like this:

```
public static final int Someid=0x7f040060; //These Id is cause error. Also check that under which  class these line contains[Either layout or id or watever].Please check twice that "Someid" is properly mentioned R.layout.Someid or R.id.Someid under proper layout or id.
```

If it's under drawable then I'm afraid try to replace that image file

It'll take you to your resource in code.

Hope these might help you :)

Comment: Thanks, it was behind id class, I just deleted the file, clean the project and copy again, then it worked.